# ITextSharp - Draw Rectangle top left corner

Tags: itext

I'm trying to draw a rectangle to the very top left of a page using ITextSharp (5.5.13). I want to draw in the page margins.  However, the rectangle is around 25 pixels too low.  How can I draw the rectangle in the top left corner?

[image: pdf rectangle]

Below is how I'm adding the rectangle to the page:

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputPdf.FullName))
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(outputPdf.FullName, FileMode.Create)))
{    
    PdfContentByte contentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(1);    
    PdfDocument doc = contentByte.PdfDocument;

    float X = 0.0f;
    float Y = 0.0f;
    float Height = Utilities.InchesToPoints(0.50f);
    float Width = Utilities.InchesToPoints(0.50f);

    float llx = (doc.Left - doc.LeftMargin) + X;
    float lly = (doc.Top - doc.TopMargin) - (Height + Y);
    float urx = (doc.Left - doc.LeftMargin) + Width + X;
    float ury = (doc.Top - doc.TopMargin) - Y;

    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(llx, lly, urx, ury)
    {
        BackgroundColor = BaseColor.BLACK
    };

    contentByte.Rectangle(rectangle);
}
```

Below are the debug values for each aforementioned variable:

[image: debug]

Comment: could that be the top margin? Then not subtracting the margin should fix this.

Comment: Not subtracting TopMargin places the ury coordinate off the page.

Comment: *"Not subtracting TopMargin places the ury coordinate off the page."* - now *that* is weird. `doc.Top` is meant to be the top of the doc. Unless you use some crop box, that is. Do you? In that case you have to take that into account...

Comment: I'm using a PdfStamper and PdfReader  -- I've edited the question to include that.

Comment: Ah. That's a very important piece of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use a `PdfStamper`, the `PdfDocument` you can retrieve from its parts does not contain sensible information, it merely is a dummy object.

Thus, don't try to determine the page size from that `PdfDocument doc`, instead use the appropriate methods or properties of your `PdfReader reader`, e.g.

```
    /** Gets the crop box without taking rotation into account. This
    * is the value of the /CropBox key. The crop box is the part
    * of the document to be displayed or printed. It usually is the same
    * as the media box but may be smaller. If the page doesn't have a crop
    * box the page size will be returned.
    * @param index the page number. The first page is 1
    * @return the crop box
    */
    virtual public Rectangle GetCropBox(int index)
```

Comment: What are the appropriate methods to determining the correct top left coordinate?

Comment: Start by using the crop box. For documents with non-zero rotation (which you can retrieve using `GetPageRotation`) you'll have to take it into account.